# Cest technique for using Elmah for logging throughout code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, elmah

We currently have Elmah for logging but is there a good technique to actually log?  Rather than pollute the code with lots of logging statements is there another way?

I'm thinking it would be awesome to attribute a class with a custom attribute that says log when something happens. I realize this would probably either mean the logging is too heavy and probably not useful.

Just thinking out loud and wondering if anyone had any experiences other than having lots of myDependency.LogMessage("") throughout their code..?

Thanks

Comment: For example you can override OnException event and then log instead if using try catch...

Comment: thanks for that.  That might be the next best option.

Comment: questionable slightly off topic but would you put try catches around sql calls and then log the error

Comment: I do it because I am afraid there be a connection problem..